# Tab bar not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

The tab bar for this project isn`t showing up, instead it just shows a black screen.This tab bar is enter in pragmatically in application launch in app delegate.

```
main_tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
viewcontroller = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
viewcontroller.title =@"Home";
UINavigationController *nav =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];

viewcontroller1 = [[SearchViewController alloc]init];
viewcontroller1.title =@"Search";
UINavigationController *nav1 =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller1];


tabs_array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nav,nav1, nil];
main_tab.viewControllers=tabs_array;
[self.window addSubview:main_tab.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

Comment: Do you have xib files for HomeViewController and SearchViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this line

```
   [self.window addSubview:main_tab.view];
```

With this

```
    self.window.rootViewController = main_tab;
```